# How can I save lines from terminal to a text file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I made a simple bash script that pack a file and then upload it, if everything is fine I am getting some `http://` links to my stuff as output I want to know how can I copy those links automaticaly to a file or variable? Also I am getting some lines which are not starting with `http://` but with `#` for instance how can I delete them and add blank lines in this spot?

Comment: Could we have an example output and an example of what you want? Can we see the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To capture script output to a file, use:

```
script.sh >file.txt
```

To remove comments (lines starting with `#`) but leave the blank in their place, use:

```
script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//' >file.txt
```

To do all of the above while also displaying the information on the terminal, use:

```
script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//' | tee file.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `>` is the shell's symbol for redirection.  It tells the shell to take whatever was going to stdout and redirect to the named file instead.
- `sed` is a line-by-line editing utility.  Here we use the `sed` substitute command which looks like `s/old/new/` where `old` is any regular expression.  In our case, `old` is `^#.*` where `^` matches at the beginning of a line, `#` matches the hash symbol, and `.*` is a wildcard to match anything that follows.  In our case, `new` is empty.  Thus,  `sed 's/^#.*//'` replaces lines that begin with `#` with a blank line.
- `tee` is a utility used to make a copy of stdout.   `tee file.txt` will take whatever it finds on stdin and (a) save it to file `file.txt` while at the same time (b) send it to stdout.  If want to append to `file.txt` instead of overwrite it, we can use `tee -a file.txt` where the `-a` option tells `tee` to append.

### Refinements

#### Adding text from another .txt file at the start of this file.txt

To place the contents of `first.txt` at the start of `file.txt`:

```
{ cat first.txt; script.sh; } >file.txt
```

#### Copy only lines starting with http://

For selecting lines according to some pattern without modifying them, `grep` is the right tool:

```
script.sh | grep '^http' >file.txt
```

#### Copying from first line with http://*

`sed` allows one to select a range of lines.  Here, we use the range `/^http/,$` where `/^http/` is the first line encountered that starts with `http` and `$` is sed's symbol for the last line in the input.  `p` tells `sed` to print lines that match that range:

```
script.sh | sed -n '/^http/,$ p'
```

#### Combine Adding text from another file and copying from first line with http://*

```
{ cat first.txt; script.sh; } | sed -n '/^http/,$ p' >file.txt
```

#### Add a blank line after every line starting with `http`

Here we use `sed` again.  When we find a line that starts with `http`, we add a newline `\n` to the end of that line:

```
script.sh | sed  's/^http.*/&\n/'
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this solution, one last question. How about if I want to add text from another .txt file at the start of this file.txt, as for output is there a way to copy only linest starting with http:// or to start copying from first line with http://* because I have a lot unnecessary output from adding to archive command.

Comment: script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//' | tee file.txt  it isn't working, it doesn't display any information on terminal

Comment: @John `script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//' | tee file.txt` works fine for me.  Let's debug it on your end.  Please try (a) `script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//'` and (b) `script.sh | tee file.txt` and tell me what happens in each case.  If any error messages appear, please quote them in their entirety.

Comment: @John I have added to the answer solutions to your other queries about (a) adding some text, (b) selecting only the http lines and (c) skipping all lines before the first http line.

Comment: I am getting > while executing "script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//'". But "script.sh | sed 's/^#.*//'" results in executing script and making a file.txt with all output. Is there a way to combine Adding text from another .txt file at the start of this file.txt and Copying from first line with http://* . Also how can I add blank line between different http adresses for example http://www.x* (twice or more than blank line) http://www.y* (couple of links than blank line) and last one http://z

Comment: I think I know where I made a mistake I use couple of echo in my script which sed prevented from showing. Is there a way to run sed after executing all function from my script?

Comment: @John I think that I have added all the cases that you have asked for.  Let me know if there are any remaining issues.